# Python if statement no cap check

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a input that the user types in something
Example

```
Test = input( 'Type in something' )
if Test == 'SOMETHING' :
    print( 'You idiot!' )
```

How do I ignore the if the word something is in all caps or non caps example:
Something
SOMETHING
SoMeThinG

Sorry My Grammar is so bad It's hard to word these things

Comment: @Adriaan It's caused by a very rare bug in SOUP :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if Test.upper() == "something".upper(): print("You idiot")
```

What about making the two parts of the equatation upper/lower?

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> Test = input("type in something ")
type in something SomeTHING
>>> Test.upper() == "something".upper()
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make everything lowercase and strip whitespace

```
Test.lower().strip()
```

Provided `SOMETHING` is in lowercase.